# Gnuplot auto-size?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I'm able to create a graph with gnuplot. I use this template to do it :

```
f(w) = (strlen(w) > 10 ? word(w, 1) . "\n" . word(w, 2) : w)

set title "TITLE"
set terminal png truecolor size 960, 720 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/var/www/html/CLUSTER_NAME.png"
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set key center top
set grid
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set boxwidth 0.7 relative
set yrange [*:*]
set format y "%g%%"
set datafile separator ","
plot 'test1.txt' using 2:xtic(f(stringcolumn(1))) title " CPU consumption (%) ", \
'' using 3 title " RAM consumption (%)", \
'' using 0:($2+1):(sprintf("%g%%",$2)) with labels notitle, \
'' using 0:($3+1):(sprintf("     %g%%",$3)) with labels notitle
```

TITLE and CLUSTER_NAME are just names that allow me to make a sed via another script to replace these names with the right ones.

At the beginning, I was using this to manage the size of my graph:

```
set yrange [0:]
```

But now, I use this to automatically manage the size :

```
set yrange[*:*]
```

The problem is : for some graph, either some percentages overlap, or the percentages go out of the frame, or the space between the bar and the percentage is too large...

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/18/5/1556891635-cluster-cpy-01.png
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/18/5/1556891641-cluster-mo1-erp-bb-01.png

Isn't there an option that allows me to manage this automatically, so that the percentages don't overlap anymore etc... ?

I think we have to play with canvas size management,  but I don't know how... Can you help me?

Comment: `$2+1` adds 1 on Y axis to position of percentage label; the count of spaces in `"     %g%%"` is how far a label is from the first bar. For example, in the first plot you can use `$2+0.2` and `"________%g%%"` where '_' is a space. To manage it automatically, use adds as a part of whole scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using histogram, you can also use `with boxes` and shift them in x-direction as needed. With this, I guess it is easier to set the label automatically at "nice" positions. The offsets are in in characters. I guess you have to `set yrange` manually, otherwise you will have the minimum and maximum on the border of the graph.

**Code:**

```
### histogram like with boxes and labels
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
07.2018 12 9
08.2018 14 9
09.2018 13 10
10.2018 16 10
11.2018 16 10
12.2018 16 10
01.2019 15 10
02.2019 15 10
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
July 2018, 47, 18
August 2018, 70, 19
September 2018, 36, 21
October 2018, 20, 21
November 2018, 44, 21
December 2018, 36, 21
January 2019, 30, 21
February 2019, 31, 22
EOD

set bmargin 3
set boxwidth 0.3 relative
set xdata time
set yrange [0:20]
set format y "%g%%"
Month(s) = strftime("%B\n%Y",strptime("%m.%Y",s))
set xtics offset first 0.2

plot \
    $Data1 u ($0-0.2):2:xtic(Month(strcol(1))) w boxes fc rgb "red" fs solid 1.0 t "CPU consumption (%)", \
     '' u ($0+0.2):3 w boxes fc rgb "green" fs solid 1.0 t "RAM consumption (%)", \
     '' u ($0-0.2):2:(sprintf("%g%%",$2)) w labels center offset 0,0.7 notitle, \
     '' u ($0+0.2):3:(sprintf("%g%%",$3)) w labels center offset 0,0.7 notitle

pause -1

set datafile separator ","
Month(n) = word(strcol(n),1)."\n".word(strcol(n),2)
set yrange[0:75]
plot \
    $Data2 u ($0-0.2):2:xtic(Month(1)) w boxes fc rgb "red" fs solid 1.0 t "CPU consumption (%)", \
     '' u ($0+0.2):3 w boxes fc rgb "green" fs solid 1.0 t "RAM consumption (%)", \
     '' u ($0-0.2):2:(sprintf("%g%%",$2)) w labels center offset 0,0.7 notitle, \
     '' u ($0+0.2):3:(sprintf("%g%%",$3)) w labels center offset 0,0.7 notitle
### end of code
```

**Edit:**

I changed the format of `$Data2` to your original input format `July 2018, 47, 18`. 
To handle this format you need to add the following lines before the second plot (above already inserted).

```
set datafile separator ","
Month(n) = word(strcol(n),1)."\n".word(strcol(n),2)
```

and change the line:

```
plot \
    $Data2 u ($0-0.2):2:xtic(Month(1)) w boxes ...
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm very interested by your proposition, but when I try to use your gnuplot code with my .csv ( looks like July 2018,19%,69%, with many lines ), I have this error : 

" test1.txt:1:         line 0: illegal month "

Do you know why this error appears ?

Comment: sorry, I changed the data format to `07.2018 47 18`. Now, I will change the `$Data2` to your original format: `July 2018, 47, 18`.

Comment: Thank you for you help @theozh !
If I understand correctly, the first plot is for the first graph and the second plot for the second graph... I need one graph, so I delete the elements of the first graph and for the second graph, I replace `plot $Data2` by `plot test1.txt', the file where are my datas. But I think, I have a problem :

* Gnuplot error => [http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/24/4/1560427398-aaaa.png]
* Graph => [ http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/24/4/1560427438-cluster.png ]
* Gnu code => [ https://pastebin.com/fKxQZH1Y ]

Comment: the first link to the error message...  page not found. Could you please check?

Comment: Oh, yes of course !

Here : [link] http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/24/5/1560520013-aaaaa.png

Comment: hm, I don't see what causes the error. Your code works fine with my gnuplot. Minor typo: in the last plotting line it should be `+` not `-`,i.e. `...using ($0+0.2):3 ...`